# Invisible, interactable objects in AS3 -- how to code efficient invisibility?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, optimization, rendering, alpha

Alpha invisibility.

I currently define circular regions on some images as "hot spots". For instance, I could have my photo on screen and overlay a circle on my head. To check for interaction with my head in realtime, I would returnOverlaps and do some manipulation on all objects overlapping the circle. For debugging, I make the circle yellow with alpha 0.5, and for release I decrease alpha to 0, making the circle invisible (as it should be).

Does this slow down the program? Is there another way to make the circle itself invisible while still remaining capable of interaction? Is there some way to color it "invisible" without using a (potentially) costly alpha of 0? Cache as bitmap matrix? Or some other efficient way to solve the "hot spot" detection without using masks?

Comment: You'd be best of checking for collisions using actual values rather than `hitTestObject()`, in which case you wouldn't even need the DisplayObjects for the check and could simply remove them from the DisplayList when you want them to be invisible and add them back when you want to see them again. That would be the most efficient possible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just a few invisible display objects should not slow it down that much, but having many could. I think a more cleaner option may be to just handle it all in code, rather then have actual invisible display objects on the stage.

For a circle, you would define the center point and radius. Then to get if anyone clicked on it, you could go:

```
var xDist:Number = circle.x - mousePoint.x;
var yDist:Number = circle.y - mousePoint.y;

if((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist) <= (circle.radius * circle.radius)){
    // mousePoint is within circle
} else {
    // mousePoint is outside of circle
}
```

If you insist on using display objects to set these circular hit areas (sometimes it can be easier visually, then by numbers), you could also write some code to read those display objects (and remove them from being rendered) in to get their positions and radius size.

---

added method:

```
// inputX and inputY are the hotspot's x and y positions, and inputRadius is the radius of the hotspot
function hitTestObj(inputA:DisplayObject, inputX:int, inputY:int, inputRadius:int):Boolean {
    var xDist:Number = inputX - inputA.x;
    var yDist:Number = inputY - inputA.y;
    var minDist:Number = inputRadius + (inputA.width / 2);
    return (((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) =< (minDist * minDist))
}
```

Comment: Thanks; how would I return a list of objects beneath a certain area? The program needs to calculate in real time what objects overlap-- and there can be limitless combinations. So I go through them one by one and return a list of all things touching it, one by one. This will become worse than N^2 complexity if I had to cycle through all objects and mathematically determine coordinates of intersection with other objects, and repeat/returnOverlaps for each object, comparing against all others. With hitTestObject, I am able to cycle through the objects only once, not once per object per cycle.

Comment: It would be the same method, except using of using hitTestObject, you would put in your own collision detection algorithm that does not rely on display objects on the stage.

I am a bit curious, how many objects do you have running at how many fps in what sort of setting? It can be worth it to avoid using a complex (but faster) algorithm when something simpler (even if slower) will do to save premature optimization and increased complexity.

Comment: 720p canvas. Up to 50 bitmap objects of variable (large) size, each with 3+ "hot spot" regions that need to sense whether any other corresponding regions of the other objects are touching/overlapping them. The program runs fairly at 60fps on the desktop, but it's struggling to maintain 30 on an Android device (also native 720p canvas). The reason it's fast is that it is a realtime simulation program -- no complex animations at all. I use other things -- priority queues, true linked lists, symbol table -- for core speed. I'm having trouble with the rendering/graphic parts like these overlaps.

Comment: I should also point out that the main ingredient is actually in returnOverlaps rather than hitTestObject -- and since many objects/regions can overlap the same hot spot (which produces various effects on attached members depending on their number/identity), I thought it was the only option. Is there some mathematical way to analyze that specific part of the image to figure out its overlaps? I was considering clearing the "fill color" (draw without a beginFill call) and lineStyle thickness to NaN (and/or lineStyle alpha to 0) -- but then would the (whole) circle still be considered "active"?

Comment: I've never had to work with flash on android before, though I do believe that rendering blended alphas can take up a fair bit of power.
 
To speed it up, I'd first try checking to see if it is actually the alphas that are the main slowdown and not the actual collision detection. If you remove the alphas and try using a pure math based collision detection, would it help?

I edited my original answer to include a method that you could use to replace hitTestObject(), though it assumes both objects are circles.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to test. Do you know of a way to replace returnOverlaps without performing a hitTestObject on everything from everything else? (This would be an N^2 algorithm.)

Comment: Yes, though they are pretty complex and most likely overkill as someone else mentioned. It more involves spatial indexing (quadtrees, geohashes) looking for an 'early out' method to avoid having to do a full more expensive collision detection (usually on more complex shapes). Since it is just circles and rectangles right now which are pretty cheap to compare and not too many ('many' being hundreds/thousands) objects, I doubt it would be worth the complexity and probably take up more power?

Answer (score 0):

An alpha=0 isn't all that costly in terms of rendering as Flash player will optimize for that (check [here](http://www.developria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html) for actual figures). Bitmap caching wouldn't be of any help as the sprite is invisible. There's other ways to perform collision detection by doing the math yourself (more relevant in games with tens or even hundreds of sprites) but that would be an overkill in your case.

Comment: How would I go about doing the calculation manually? I need to check in realtime what objects overlap a given object (the circle in my above example) and perform some math/modification on all its overlapping objects each frame. Currently hitTestObject and/or returnOverlaps gives me just the items overlapping the circle without the need to cycle through the many objects on screen.